# How to migrate Apache Archiva repository from old server to new server

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2

I'm using ***Apache Archiva 1.3*** on ***ubuntu server 12.04*** and need to upgrade on a new server with ***apache archiva 2.3***. I moved the repository from the old to the new server but when I'm accessing the *archiva* through the browser it's showing the repository but I'm not able to search it. May be there is some issue with the ***indexing***. Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had gone through the same issue, In indexing of apache Archiva.
I was having apache archiva X.X.X on a server and I had need to upgrade it to latest one on a different server so required to use the old repository.
I had successfully configured the new apache archiva 2.3 on a new server and then migrated the old repository to new server.

I had followed the below mentioned steps and its worked for me:

**Step 1:** I moved the old repository to the newly setup server from `/opt/apache-archiva-X.X.X/data/repositories/internal` to the new server with same path.

**Note :** If you have different path then specify it in `/opt/apache-archiva-2.2.3/conf/archiva.xml` file and change accordingly:

```
<managedRepository>
<location>/opt/apache-archiva-2.2.3/data/repositories/internal</location> 

<managedRepository>
<location>/opt/apache-archiva-2.2.3/data/repositories/snapshots</location>
```

**Step 2:** Search .indexer file in the above given path and remove it as old indexer file won't work with the new setup of apache archiva.

**Step 3:** Now goto browser and access the new archiva url and login as an administrator
Goto repository and scan for index and directory. It will create a new .indexer file in new setup.

Cheers !! That's all enjoy